# error: toolchain 'stable-x86_64-apple-darwin' does not have the binary `rustfmt`

Tags: rust, rustup

I've run `rustup update` to update my toolchain and saw two warnings:

```
warning: tool `rustfmt` is already installed, remove it from `/Users/<username>/.cargo/bin`, then run `rustup update` to have rustup manage this tool.
warning: tool `cargo-fmt` is already installed, remove it from `/Users/<username>/.cargo/bin`, then run `rustup update` to have rustup manage this tool.
```

I followed the instructions in the warning messages, then tried to run `rustfmt` again. I got the error

```
error: toolchain 'stable-x86_64-apple-darwin' does not have the binary rustfmt`
```

What went wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think the first part of your question isn't relevant -- right now you're just having trouble with `rustfmt` from a clean rustup install. I am too..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The most standard and reliable way to have `rustfmt` in your system is to ensure that the **`rustfmt` component is installed** in your Rustup toolchain.

```sh
rustup component add rustfmt
```

Or for a specific toolchain:

```sh
rustup component add rustfmt --toolchain nightly-2020-06-09
```

There is a possibility that the tests and builds in nightly toolchains fail, which means that those are not as likely to always have this component. The latest `stable` and `beta` toolchains will usually have it in accordance to the [No Tool Breakage Week](https://forge.rust-lang.org/#no-tools-breakage-week) policy.

In order to let Rustup  manage `rustfmt`, see the following steps:

1. Once you update Rustup to the latest version, you may receive the message `warning: tool rustfmt is already installed`. Remove the binaries from Cargo's binary folder, as suggested. `cargo uninstall rustfmt` (or `rustfmt-nightly` if you installed that) works well.
2. Run `rustup update` to let it fill in the deleted binaries with its own, managed `rustfmt` and `cargo-fmt`.
3. Ensure that the toolchain that you wish to work with is installed (e.g. `stable`)
4. Run the command above too ensure that the `rustfmt` component is installed for that toolchain.

With that done, calling `rustfmt` will work as intended:

```
$ rustup run stable rustfmt --version
rustfmt 1.4.12-stable (a828ffea 2020-03-11)
```

Or via the Cargo subcommand:

```sh
$ cargo fmt --version
rustfmt 1.4.12-stable (a828ffea 2020-03-11)
```

---

In the early days, `rustfmt` managed by Rustup could have been a bit confusing, because Rustup did not always have `rustfmt`, and would still too often emerge as a preview component which had to be installed under the name `rustfmt-preview`. There are a few relevant issues and PRs on the subject ([#1305](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1305) and [#1310](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/pull/1310)).

Comment: To add `rustfmt-preview` with that toolchain, you'll also need to install the toolchain: `rustup install nightly-2017-12-20-x86_64-apple-darwin`

Answer (score 18):

The Error tells you that you don't have the `rustfmt-preview` is not installed on the actual `*-apple-darwin`.

what you need to do is:

`rustup component add rustfmt-preview --toolchain stable-x86_64-apple-darwin`

after you'll be good to go :)

Comment: Thanks! This was what I needed for the "default" newbie install.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rustup run stable rustfmt --version
error: `toolchain 'stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' does not have th`e binary `rustfmt.exe`

$ rustup component remove rustfmt-preview --toolchain=stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
info: removing component 'rustfmt-preview'
warning: during uninstall component rustfmt-preview-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc was not found

$ rustup component add rustfmt-preview --toolchain=stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
info: downloading component 'rustfmt-preview'
info: installing component 'rustfmt-preview'

$ rustup run stable rustfmt --version
rustfmt 0.99.1-stable (da17b689 2018-08-04)
```

https://users.rust-lang.org/t/problem-with-rustfmt-on-stable/15165/7